# React-native maps: Error when I try to set latitude and longitude of initialRegion to state data

Tags: javascript, google-maps, react-native, maps, latitude-longitude

I have a screen that loads and places markers on a map based on a search form in the previous screen. I want the map window to also centre itself in the middle of all the markers. So when I use initialRegion, I set the latitude and longitude to state values whose states are set after fetching JSON from a URL. The lat and long are set to values at the centre of the markers. I want the map window to go to these coordinates, but instead, I get an error when the screen loads.

Here is the code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, AsyncStorage, Alert, FlatList, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { PrimaryButton } from '../Buttons';
import styles from './styles';
import { ListItem } from '../ListItem';
import MapView, { Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

class RestOptions extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            jsonResults: [],
            userPlaces: [],
            lat_center: null,
            lng_center: null
        }
    }

    renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>{item.rest_name}</Text>
                <Text>{item.counter}</Text>
                <Text>Distance: {item.distance} Miles</Text>
                <PrimaryButton
                    label="Set Reservation"
                    onPress={() => this.setReservation(item.rest_id)}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getSearchResults();
    }

    getSearchResults() {
        fetch('fetch url here')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            var placesArray = [];
            var latArray = [];
            var lngArray = [];
            for (key = 0; key < responseJson.rest_array.length; key = key + 1) {
                var lati_str = responseJson.rest_array[key].lat;
                var long_str = responseJson.rest_array[key].lng;
                var count_str = responseJson.rest_array[key].counter;
                var lati = parseFloat(lati_str);
                var long = parseFloat(long_str);
                var count = parseFloat(count_str);
                latArray.push(lati);
                lngArray.push(long);
                placesArray.push ({
                    coordinates: {
                        latitude: lati,
                        longitude: long
                    },
                    id: count
                });
            }
            var max_lat = Math.max.apply(null, latArray);
            var min_lat = Math.min.apply(null, latArray);
            var max_lng = Math.max.apply(null, lngArray);
            var min_lng = Math.min.apply(null, lngArray);
            var latCenter = (max_lat + min_lat) / 2;
            var lngCenter = (max_lng + min_lng) / 2;
            this.setState({lat_center: latCenter}); //setting latitude state here
            this.setState({lng_center: lngCenter}); //setting longitude state here
            this.setState({userPlaces: placesArray});
            this.setState({jsonResults: responseJson.rest_array});
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    setReservation(rest_id) {
        Alert.alert(rest_id);
        //this.props.navigation.navigate('SetReservation');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <View style={mapStyles.mapContainer}>
                    <MapView
                        style={mapStyles.map}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude: this.state.lat_center, //using latitude state here
                            longitude: this.state.lng_center, //using longitude state here
                            latitudeDelta: 0.1022,
                            longitudeDelta: 0.0821
                        }}
                    >
                        {this.state.userPlaces.map(userPlace => (
                            <MapView.Marker
                                coordinate={userPlace.coordinates}
                                key={userPlace.id}
                            />
                        ))}
                    </MapView>
                </View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.jsonResults}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
};

const mapStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    mapContainer: {
        width: '100%',
        height: 200,
    },
    map: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    },
});

export default RestOptions;
```

I get this error:

[image]

And this warning:

[image]

I have already verified that the lat_center and lng_center successfully change state to the appropriate coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s probably because your initial values for the lat_center and lng_center are null in your state object in the constructor.

`compondentDidMount` gets called after the initial render.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#mounting

> - constructor()
> - static getDerivedStateFromProps()
> - render()
> - componentDidMount()

This means that for a moment in time the values of your latitude and longitude will be null leading to these errors. You either need to set an initial value that is not null or not render your map until the coordinates have need set.

Also those 4 setState calls could be reduced to one, in something like this.

```
this.setState({
    lat_center: latCenter, 
    lng_center: lngCenter,
    userPlaces: placesArray,
    jsonResults: responseJson.rest_array
});
```

Comment: I understand now that the map is being rendered before the coordinates are set. So how do I make it render after? If I just change the initial value to something that is not null (such as some coordinates), the map just centers on those coordinates. So I need a way to render the map after the coordinates are set to what I want.

Comment: You could use a variable in your state like `mapLoaded: false` and set it to true when you have the coordinates. Then in your render function could do something like `{this.state.mapLoaded && <MapView></MapView>}` Which will render your map once `this.state.mapLoaded` has been set to true.